# How do I pass arguments to an anonymous function within a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, anonymous-function

Let's consider following example

```
function apple(fn) {
    fn();
}

apple(function(a) { // Here how do I pass an integer value for a ?
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: when you call `fn` you can pass in a number: `fn(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are passed to a function **when it is called**. So you can't per se. You have to pass them when you call it:

```
function apple(fn) {
    fn("Here you can pass an argument");
}

apple(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

If you want to define the value when you define the function, then just put it in the function:

```
function apple(fn) {
    fn();
}

apple(function() {
    console.log("Here you can hard code a value instead of using an argument");
});
```

A more complex solution would be to create a function which calls the anonymous function with arguments and then pass the new function… but that is just pointless complexity for the example you provide.

```
function apple(fn) {
    fn();
}

apple(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
}.bind(null, "Here you can pass an argument"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls the anonymous function with no arguments:

```js
function apple(fn) {
    fn(); //Here
}
```

You can pass something to it from `apple`:

```js
function apple(fn) {
    fn(0);
}

apple(function(a) {
    console.log(a); //0
});
```

Or, you can let `apple` pass arguments for your anonymous function:

```js
function apple(fn,...args) {
    fn(...args);
}

apple(function(a) {
    console.log(a); //0
}, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can bind your anonymous function, to prefix it with arguments:

```js
function apple(fn) {
    fn();
}

apple((function(a) {
    console.log(a); //0
}).bind(undefined, 0));
```